# Syntax Error: Unexpected String using jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, syntax

I am attempting to cycle through the object so that it outputs the key and value, but I keep getting the unexpected string error.  Can anyone help?

```
var obj = {
    'a.video-0': "<span>Benefits of USF\'s Online Master\'s Degree Program in Management Information Systems</span>" 
    'a.video-1': "<span>How are the courses optimally designed</span>"
};

for( key in obj ) {
    jQuery( [key] ).html(obj[key]);
});
```

Comment: `jQuery( [key] )` should be `jQuery( key )`. Not sure if this is the whole issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You are missins the ",", and you have a *)* that cause another error.

Try it:

```
var obj = {
    'a.video-0': "<span>Benefits of USF\'s Online Master\'s Degree Program in Management Information Systems</span>",
    'a.video-1': "<span>How are the courses optimally designed</span>"
};

for( key in obj ) {
    jQuery(key).html(obj[key]);
};
```

Regards.